# Why is this question too broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing-questions, closed-questions, questions

In [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/267414/was-there-a-snake-with-voldemort-when-he-killed-the-potters/267417#comment737027_267414), it is proposed that that because "this is technically three different questions" the question should be closed.

It seems to me that the question is about the interpretation of a few lines of text; it just happens to present three separate bits of confusion about the meaning. Is this really enough to render the question unfocussed or too broad?

<sup>(Perhaps the close-voters were just not familiar enough with the material to recognize that these were tightly related questions that could be answered fairly simply, but in response, I would suggest to be a little patient to see whether people more familiar with the source material are able to provide a simple answer.)</sup>

From [this meta question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7074/when-are-we-okay-with-multiple-questions-in-one) my takeaway from the highest voted answer is that the problem is when "they're obviously completely separate questions" and the concern is that one will "end up writing a list of answers in one post." I just don't see those issues arising in this case. I see them highly intertwined and that source of the confusion about those few lines of text is because of the implicit switching of perspective when the vision starts and stops. It's all connected.

Comment: That would probably be a dupe of [When are we okay with multiple-questions-in-one?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7074/when-are-we-okay-with-multiple-questions-in-one)

Comment: Thanks, I'm happy relying on that other question for a statement of the policy.

Answer (score 7):

In this instance, I think F1Krazy is being a little harsh. There are, to my mind, *two* distinct questions here rather than three;

The title and body of the main question (e.g. *'...there appears to be a snake slithering in the room. Where did [it] come from?'* / *'Did Voldemort become a snake?'*) basically a boil down to a single question (e.g. *'Where did this snake come from?'*)

OP has then appended a second question about the meaning of a phrase (e.g. *'What does "he had killed the boy, and yet he was the boy..." mean?'*), and while they're admittedly very close to each other in the book, that doesn't mean that they're necessarily closely-related enough to be considered a single question.

---

My advice is that removing the second question would immediately bring this back on topic. This question might be reserved for later (if answers to the first question don't end up touching on this to their satisfaction) or simply [asked](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as a second new question.